# using arrayList with database?

Tags: android

I'm writing an application with an internal database.
I'm getting data on database with the arrayList because I have to get different type of data. My question is: are ArrayList the best solution to get data from this database or there are others method to do that?

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: I don't have do this part. I'm asking the question before doing this, because I was looking for the fastest method.

Comment: in that case, refer to this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ArrayList is one way of reading data from a database. It will be convenient to store all the info from a column in an ArrayList, such as an ArrayList for the name column, or age columns, so on...

Another data structure that you may consider using is a Map such as a HashMap or a TreeMap. This will not only enable you to store the data values but give it a key as well, this way you can refer to the value by using its key. An example of where you may use this if you want to retrieve the names of a person and their age. By using a HashMap, the key could be the person's name and the value could be their age. This would make it easy to retrieve the person's age based on their name.

Maps are used to put information into a database, as can be found by [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) from Android Developers. The Android Developers documentation also shows that Lists can be used to read data. Essentially, it comes down to your uses. If you are reading multiple columns, you may consider creating multiple Lists whereas if you were reading from two columns, such as name and age, you may consider using a HashMap that way each age corresponds to a name and it is easy to retrieve that age from the name.

I hope that this answer has given you some insight and input into which data structure you have decided to use, but ultimately, it is your choice.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's  much useful for me.

Comment: If you found it to be useful, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Since you found it useful, if you would mark it as accepted or upvote it, it would help others find an answer to their similar problems.

Comment: @Gioele.sandrin, if the answer is useful for you or solves your problem, mark it as accepted to help future readers

Comment: Thanks. I am happy that you were helped by my answer.